# How do you remove iptables rules?

Tags: iptables, dnscrypt-proxy

A while ago, I setup an iptables rule to forward port 53 on my computer to port 5553. Now I want to delete it, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to stay deleted after reboots. I do not have iptables-persistent installed. What config file do I need to edit to fix these?

Comment: All rules or just the port forward rule?

Comment: How did you add it in the first place?  If you don't have `iptables-persistent` installed, then it could be very difficult to figure out the cause of how it's readding the rules.  Do you use `ufw` or something else?

Comment: "A while ago, I setup an iptables"  You stored that rule by creating a file and have that file load at some point? I would asssume? So remove/alter that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. There was a line in `/etc/rc.local` that added the rule on boot.